# RTCPeerConnection cannot be resolved

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, kurento

I am building a WebRTC based web app that uses Kurento-util.js. Below is the gist of the code from Kurento-util.js that gives the error

```
if (!pc) {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    if (useDataChannels && !dataChannel) {
        // Do your thing ....
    }
}
```

Live feed from camera is available all fine on Desktop browsers like Chrome/ Firefox. But the issue comes when the same web page runs on a mobile browser like Chrome. FYI, I am using the latest mobile Chrome browser (55) that supports WebRTC. I investigated the issue and in the above code, "RTCPeerConnection cannot be resolved". It is only given by mobile browser but the code is working fine for PC browsers.

[This is the error I get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKgY.png)

Comment: Then that browser doesn't support `RTCPeerConnection`/WebRTC.

Comment: Try to check Chrome android (61) it declared as available [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection)